# Reset my timer countdown

Tags: counter, countdown

i have a countdown timer that is logging out the user when it goes to 0:00. in fact it's calling a logout() function. this is my javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//timer
    var mins = 60;
    var sec = 00;
 var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    setInterval(function(){
    var a = new Date();
        timer.innerHTML = mins +":"+((''+sec).length>1?'':'0')+sec ;
        sec--;
        if (sec == -1) {
            mins--;
            sec = 59;
        }
  if (mins==0 && sec ==00) {
   logout();
  }
        },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><img src="http://www.tridimas.gr/img/tmrel.png" style="margin:0 10px -3px 0; cursor:pointer;" onClick="reset counter"/></td>
<td style="font:12px Verdana;" id="timer"></td></tr></table>
```

i want to reset the counter back to 60 minutes with onclick the image.
how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like jquery, add an id to the image:

```
<img id="resetImg" src="http://www.tridimas.gr/img/tmrel.png" style="margin:0 10px -3px 0; cursor:pointer;"/>
```

then change you block of javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//timer
    var mins = 60;
    var sec = 00;
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    setInterval(function(){
    var a = new Date();
        timer.innerHTML = mins +":"+((''+sec).length>1?'':'0')+sec ;
        sec--;
        if (sec == -1) {
            mins--;
            sec = 59;
        }
        if (mins==0 && sec ==00) {
            logout();
        }
        },1000);

    var img = $("#resetImg");
    img.on("click", function(){
        mins = 60;
        sec = 0;
    });
});
```